# discord.py wait_for how to get only the content of the message instead of its id

Tags: python, discord

so im trying to get the content of the message using wait_for

```
async def invest(ctx):
def check(m):
  return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
await ctx.channel.send("ok how much do you wanna invest")
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
await ctx.channel.send(msg)
if isinstance(msg, int):
 await ctx.channel.send("ok")
```

i want the content of the message but instead it gives me:
<Message id=9(id of the message) channel=<TextChannel id=(id of the channel) name='general' position=0 nsfw=True news=False category_id=934051866847875093> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=(idk member id) name='ThatGuyWithDrip' discriminator='6908' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=(i guess its guild id) name='discord server name' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=(member count)>> flags=>

nvm i just needed to use msg.content instead of msg, thx cubix

Comment: Did you try ``await ctx.channel.send(msg.content)`` ?

Comment: no i didnt. and it works, thanks